# Rigidity of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, zariski-topology, deformation-theory

$V$ a finite-dimensional real vector space ($\dim V=n$).
$$S=\wedge^2V\otimes V=\{b:V\times V\to V,\ \text{skew-symmetric, bilinear maps}\}$$
A Lie bracket on $V$ is an element $\mu$ of $S$ satisfying the Jacobi identity:
$$\mu(x,\mu(y,z))+\mu(y,\mu(z,x))+\mu(z,\mu(x,y))=0,\ \forall x,y,z\in V.$$
$\mathcal{G}=\{\text{Lie brackets on}\ V\}\subset S$ and $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathcal{G}$:
$$g\cdot\mu(x,y):=g\left(\mu(g^{-1}(x),g^{-1}(y))\right).$$
$(V,\mu)$ is **rigid** if every Lie bracket $\mu'$ sufficiently close to $\mu$, $(V,\mu')$ is isomorphic to $(V,\mu)$. i.e. it exists $g\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ close to the identity such that $\mu'=g\cdot\mu$ (or the orbit of $\mu$ is open in $\mathcal{G}$).

> What is the relevant topology here: $\mathcal{G}$ is a vector subspace of $S$ endowed with the euclidean topology. Is this topology equivalent to the Zariski one (when $\mathcal{G}$ is identified to the family of constant structures, i.e. as an algebraic variety).

I would like to study the following example on a $3$-dimensional real vector space $V=<e_1,e_2,e_3>$ for the Lie bracket
$$\mu(e_1,e_2)=e_3,\ \mu(e_1,e_3)=-e_2,\ \mu(e_2,e_3)=0.$$
Since the orbit $O(\mu)$ is isomorphic to the quotient $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R})/G_\mu$ where $G_\mu$ is the isotropy group $G_\mu=\{g\in\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{R}),\ g\cdot\mu=\mu\}$. In order to the orbit to be open, I have to show that $\dim O(\mu)=\dim\mathcal{G}$.

> What is the dimension of $\mathcal{G}$? $\dim S=3^2(3-1)/2=9$.

$g=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}\in G_\mu$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
0=&[g(e_2),g(e_3)]=&-(a_{12}a_{33}-a_{13}a_{32})\,e_2+(a_{12}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{22})\,e_3\\
-g(e_2)=&[g(e_1),g(e_3)]=&-(a_{11}a_{33}-a_{13}a_{31})\,e_2+(a_{11}a_{23}-a_{13}a_{21})\,e_3\\
g(e_3)=&[g(e_1),g(e_2)]=&-(a_{11}a_{32}-a_{12}a_{31})\,e_2+(a_{11}a_{22}-a_{12}a_{21})\,e_3
\end{align*}
i.e. $a_{12}=0=a_{13}$ and six other independent quadratic equations. So $\dim G_\mu=8$, $\dim O(\mu)=9-8=1$ and $\mu$ is not rigid.

> Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach. Your Lie algebra $L$ is solvable, sometimes denoted by $\mathfrak{r}_{3,-1}(\Bbb R)$. Every solvable Lie algebra of dimension $2\le n\le 7$ is rigid if and only if it *complete* (i.e., has zero center and all derivations are inner). Since $\mathfrak{r}_{3,-1}(\Bbb R)$ is not complete, it is not rigid. So you are right. Actually, the derivation algebra has dimension $4$, which is $3+1$. Here $\dim {\rm Inn}(L)=3$. So not all derivations are inner.

Comment: Thanks Dietrich for the nice answer, although it's the first time I encounter this result!

Comment: Looking at the derivation algebra is very useful to study degenerations of Lie algebras and rigid Lie algebras.

Comment: That's very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: A nice answer, but I would like to learn more about the topology: why Zariski open is equivalent to euclidean open for the orbit ?

Comment: For $K=\Bbb C$ an orbit $O(\mu)$ is Zariski-open if and only if it is Euclidean-open. This follows from general results, see for example Borel's book on Linear Algebraic Groups. Here $GL(n)$ is a reductive algebraic group acting.

Comment: Thanks for the Borel reference!